# Excel Range Reference

Tags: vba, excel, range

Let me preface this question by saying I am not super technical so much of my verbiage may seem obscure..

On sheet1 I have three seperate horizontal ranges of cells (3 seperate series of steps):

- `A1:D1`
- `A2:C2`
- `A3:E3`

On sheet two, I'd like to link to create live links to these ranges, such that if I change information on sheet1, it will be automatically reflected in sheet2.

The catch is, that on sheet2, I want the ranges to be listed after one another in one row, to create one long series of steps.

Range1-->Range2-->Range3 (all on one row)

How do I ensure that if I add an additional step to, say, the first range on sheet1, that on sheet 2, the new cell will be added and the following cells will all be pushed over to the right by one cell?

Comment: You know that you can do something like `='sheet1'!A1` in the cells of your second sheet?

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate ranges that might grow, start from the first cell and then find the last occupied cell with `End(xlToRight)`. Once you've found all the range extents, you can combine them with an array UDF:

```
Function ConcatRanges(ParamArray ranges()) As Variant()
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ret() As Variant
    ReDim ret(1 To 1, 1 To (Application.Caller.Columns.Count))
    Dim RetIdx&, i&, cell As Range
    RetIdx = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(ranges)
        For Each cell in Application.Range(ranges(i), ranges(i).End(xlToRight))
            ret(1, RetIdx) = cell.Value
            RetIdx = RetIdx + 1
        Next
    Next
    For RetIdx = RetIdx To UBound(ret, 2)
        ret(1, RetIdx) = vbNullString
    Next
    ConcatRanges = ret
End Function
```

For your example, you'd call it like this:

```
=ConcatRanges(Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A2, Sheet1!A3)
```